# Easy way to have return type be SETOF table plus additional fields?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2, composite-types

I'm writing a PL/pgSQL stored procedure that will return a set of records; each record contains all the fields of an existing table (call it Retailer, which has two fields: retailer_key and retailer_name). This, of course, works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc_Find_retailers
 (IN p_Store_key INT)
   RETURNS SETOF Retailer
   AS $$ ...`
```

Now I want to update the sp so that it returns an additional two fields to the 'end' of each returned record. I can do something such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc_Find_store
 (IN p_Store_key INT)
   RETURNS TABLE (
      retailer_key int,
      retailer_name varchar(50),
      addl_field_1 int,
      addl_field_2 double precision)
   AS $$ ...
```

In the real world, my Retailer table has 50 fields (not the two in my example), so enumerating all those fields in the RETURNS TABLE clause is tedious. Is there any shortcut to this, so that I might say something such as (I realize I'm making stuff up here that's syntactically illegal, but I'm doing it to give you the flavor of what I'm looking for):

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc_Find_store
 (IN p_Store_key INT)
   RETURNS (SETOF Store,
      addl_field_1 int,
      addl_field_2 double precision)
   AS $$ ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *could* return a whole row as composite type and add some more:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_rowplus()
  RETURNS TABLE (rec demo, add_int int, add_txt text) AS
$func$
SELECT d, 5, 'baz'::text FROM demo d;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

But then, when you use the simple call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_rowplus();
```

You get the row from table `demo` as separate composite type. You'd have to call:

```
SELECT (rec).*,  add_int, add_txt FROM f_rowplus();
```

to get all *individual* columns. Parentheses required.

Postgres is a bit inconsistent here. If you create a function with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_row2()
  RETURNS TABLE (rec demo) AS
...
```

then the composite type `demo` is silently converted into individual columns (decomposed). No link to the original composite type remains. You cannot reference the declared output column `rec` at all, since that has been replaced with the columns of the decomposed type. This call would result in an error message:

```
SELECT rec FROM f_row2();  -- error!
```

Same here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_row3(OUT rec demo)
  RETURNS SETOF demo AS
...
```

**However**, as soon as you add *any* more `OUT` columns, the composite type is preserved as declared (not decomposed) and you can:

```
SELECT rec FROM f_rowplus();
```

with the first function.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b29b896ec5419e2144253149978b1604)* - demonstrating all variants
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8b7bc/2)</sub>

#### Asides

When using a function returning multiple columns in the `FROM` list (as table function) and decomposing in the `SELECT` list like this:

```
SELECT (rec).* FROM f_rowplus();
```

... the function is still evaluated *once* only - while calling *and* decomposing in the `SELECT` list directly like this:

```
SELECT (f_rowplus()).*;  -- also: different result
```

... would evaluate *once for every column* in the return type. See:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271)

In **Postgres 14** or later, you can also use standard-SQL syntax:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_rowplus_std()
  RETURNS TABLE (rec demo, add_int int, add_txt text)
  LANGUAGE sql PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT d, 5, 'baz'::text FROM demo d;
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Comment: All the research still seems to have the same conclusion on pg 12. Great job!

Comment: @ps2goat: Just updated & tested on pg 14, still the same.

Comment: Personally I would return a jsonb field containing dynamic keys and values