# POSTGRES/POSTGIS dynamically define a RETURN table (column type, name) for subsequent loop

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

what I would like to achieve is to execute the st_Intersection(clipper_geom, clipped_geom) on number of records coming from a table.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html

POSTGIS Intersection does not support the processing of multiple geometries natively, differently from st_intersects() and I had to design a function (returning a table) that selects all the features intersecting with st_intersects my clipper area, loop through each result of this query and execute the intersection st_intersection on every single record, the "geom" field and "clipped_geom_wkt" are the ones that actually records the clipped geometry.

The function works, but I need a different one for every table we want to produce the clipping. What I would like to achieve is to dynamically read the input table (column name and type) and to define both in the RETURN statement.

All fields names and types are the same the only one that will be updated is geom and a new one will be added is clipped_geom_wkt.

I tried to search Stack Overflow and I found examples on how to create dynamic table structure but none of what I have found then perform a subsequent LOOP over the first results, where the column names have to be matched to insert/ update the new data.

This is what I have come up so far, but I am usure about how to perform the LOOP part, to add the clipped_geom_wkt field and update the geom field. In some responses on here I see that is advisable to set the RETURN type to TABLE
if more fields are added to SETOF

[Easy way to have return type be SETOF table plus additional fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821482/easy-way-to-have-return-type-be-setof-table-plus-additional-fields)

But at the same time what I also see is that dynamically generated columns are only supported if the table definition is returned as SETOF

[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

[PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clip_palin_polygon_complete(clipped_table text,clipper_geom text, age_sequence VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (rec clipped_table, clipped_geom_wkt text)) AS $$ --not sure if this is the right way to do it...
DECLARE var_r record;
BEGIN
    FOR var_r IN (
        SELECT * FROM clipped_table 
        WHERE clipped_table.seq IN (age_sequence)
        AND ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText(clipper_geom,4326), clipped_table.geom)
    )
    LOOP
        /* 
        these are the original table fields that I would like to keep and match
        dynamically with any table I have as input (clipped_table)
        objectid := var_r.objectid;
        seq := var_r.seq;
        age := var_r.age;
        primary_lithology := var_r.primary_lithology;
        confidence := var_r.confidence;
        area_calculated := var_r.area_calculated;*/

        --below there are the only two fields that need modifying
        geom := (
            SELECT ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText(clipper_geom, 4326), var_r.geom) AS geom);
        clipped_geom_wkt := (
            SELECT
            ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText(clipper_geom,4326), var_r.geom)) AS clipped_geom_wkt);
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: It looks a lot like the trail/country intersection example from the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html), which is done via a single query, not a function