# Return entire row from table and columns from other tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I'm using postgresql 14 and trying to return an entire record from a table in addition to columns from different tables. The catch is, that I don't want to write all the titles in the record. I tried working with the guide lines here [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821482/easy-way-to-have-return-type-be-setof-table-plus-additional-fields), but I'm getting different errors. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_license_by_id(license_id_ integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(rec tbl_licenses, template_name character varying, company_name character varying)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable AS (
        SELECT 
            (rec).*, B.company_name, C.template_name 
            -- Tried using A instead of (rec).* with error: column "a" has pseudo-type record
        FROM 
        (
            (SELECT * FROM tbl_licenses) A
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT * FROM tbl_customers) B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT * FROM tbl_templates) C on A.template_id = C.template_id
        )
    );
    UPDATE tempTable
    SET license = '1'
    WHERE tempTable.license IS NOT NULL;
    RETURN QUERY ( 
        SELECT * FROM tempTable
    );
    
    DROP TABLE tempTable;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$;
```

I'm calling the function like `SELECT rec FROM get_license_by_id(1);`
but getting:

> ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
> DETAIL:  Returned type integer does not match expected type tbl_licenses in column 1.

Comment: Your query does not define an alias `rec` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the A alias to the correct record type. However the nested derived tables are not necessary for the other tables. If you use a coalesce() for the `license` column in the SELECT, then you get get rid of the inefficient creation and update of the temp table as well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_license_by_id(license_id_ integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(rec tbl_licenses, template_name character varying, company_name character varying)
  LANGUAGE sql
  STABLE
AS $BODY$
  SELECT a::tbl_licenses, -- this is important
         B.company_name, C.template_name 
  FROM (
    select license_id, customer_id, ... other columns ..., 
           coalesce(license, '1') as license -- makes the temp table unnecessary
    from tbl_licenses A
  ) a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_customers B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_templates C on A.template_id = C.template_id
  where a.license_id = license_id_;
$BODY$
;
```

Comment: Thanks! It compiles, however, I can't get the record spread to columns AND customer_name, template_name, it's either a spread rec only or rec as it's own single column with the others.
In addition, is there a way to shorten writing all tbl_licenses columns?
Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `select (rec).* ... from get_license_by_id(...);` But at one point or another you will have to write the columns - especially if you want to replace values during retrieval (as you do with the `license` column. If you want separate columns in the result, I would define the function to return individual columns. What's the reason for trying this with a record type as a column? Surely writing the columns once in a function (or maybe even a view) isn't such a big deal.

Comment: It was mainly to save the time of writing them as the method itself can be used in other functions containing many columns.

Comment: I managed to get it work by writing the single columns first so: SELECT company_name, template_name, (rec).*  FROM get_license_by_id(1);
Thanks again for all your help!